# Pytest TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'browser'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I try to add `pytest_addoption(parser)` in my `confest.py`. [Here are the official  Pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html)

But if I try to start test I see

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'browser'
```

`Confest.py`

```
import pytest
from fixture.application import Application
__author__ = 'Max'

fixture = None

@pytest.fixture
def app(request):
    global fixture
    browser = request.config.getoption("--browser")
    if fixture is None:
        fixture = Application(browser=browser)
    else:
        if not fixture.is_valid:
            fixture = Application(browser=browser)
    fixture.session.ensure_login(username="somename", password="somepassword")
    return fixture

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    # hooks for browsers
    parser.addoption("--browser", action="store", default="chrome")
```

`fixture/application.py`

```
from selenium import webdriver

class Application:

    def __init__(self,browser):
        if browser == "chrome":
            self.wd = webdriver.Chrome()
        elif browser == "firefox":
            self.wd = webdriver.Firefox()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unrecognized browser %s" % browser)
```

Comment: Please review the indentation; it's important in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

You should use `Application(browser)` (at Confest.py).

Another similar problem: [__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986089/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-user)

## Explanation

When you make `Application(browser=browser)`, you are trying to use [keyword parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=keyword%20parameters#how-can-i-pass-optional-or-keyword-parameters-from-one-function-to-another).

## Example with keyword parameter

```
from selenium import webdriver


class Application:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs['browser'] == "chrome":
            self.wd = webdriver.Chrome()
        elif kwargs['browser'] == "firefox":
            self.wd = webdriver.Firefox()
        else:
            raise ValueError("Unrecognized browser %s" % kwargs['browser'])
```