# How to fill the 'sender' automatically when sending a message to another user? CBV

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I know that I can use 3rd party messaging libraries, but I want to learn how to make my own. I've been struggling to automatically set the sender in my `CreateMessageForm`.

My error code: `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sender'`

Forms

```
class CreateMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    reciever = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm','placeholder':'Send to'}))
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder':'Enter message subject', 'rows':'1'}))
    msg_content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder':'Writing your message', 'rows':'10'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = (
            'sender', 'reciever', 'title', 'msg_content',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        sender = kwargs.pop('sender') # To get request.user. Do not use kwargs.pop('user', None) due to potential security hole
        super(CreateMessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

View

```
class MessageCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Message

    fields = ['sender', 'reciever', 'title', 'msg_content']

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """This method is what injects forms with their keyword
            arguments."""
        # grab the current set of form #kwargs
        kwargs = super(MessageCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        # Update the kwargs with the sender_id
        kwargs['sender'] = self.request.user.id
        return kwargs
```

Models

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="reciever", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
```

I've looked at other threads, but wasn't able to fix it.

I tried following this [__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986089/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-user)

How can I fix this so that my form automatically fills in the message 'sender' automatically?

Comment: You need to clarify: do you want to show a form with the sender pre-filled, or do you want the message to always be from the current user? In which case you don't need it on the form at all, so see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want the sender to always be from current user, and eventually code the receiver to be based on the user' profile. I will take a look at the documentation. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just wanted to give you and update. I got it working using the views (yay).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DanielRoseman (for the guidance and the link he provided), I figured out how to make this work. This is the code in case you have the same problem.

```
class MessageCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Message

    fields = ['reciever', 'title', 'msg_content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.sender = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class CreateMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    reciever = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm','placeholder':'Send to'}))
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder':'Enter message subject', 'rows':'1'}))
    msg_content = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-sm', 'placeholder':'Writing your message', 'rows':'10'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = (
            'reciever', 'title', 'msg_content',
        )
```