# Redis not working. __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'

Tags: python, django, pandas, redis, celery

i am trying to run the celery -A project worker -l info. But each time it returns an error like **init** got unexpected error. Kindly Help.
Thanks in advance.

my settings file:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Nairobi'
```

celery file:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# setting the Django settings module.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
app = Celery('project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Looks up for task modules in Django applications and loads them
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task():
    print('Request')
```

**init** file

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

Comment: It would help if you included relevant parts of the code.

Comment: Please check this relevant error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986089/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-user

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.   I'm not seeing any references to 'username'

Comment: i am not using a username anywhere. this might be the issue in redis. my project only has a celery setup

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 11):

I just solved the problem by installing a Redis bundle.

```
pip install "celery[redis]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue are most likely due to a regression in Kombu when connecting to redis. The way forward is either to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/celery/kombu/issues/1419 or to pin Kombu to a lower version. (I pinned Kombu to 5.0.2)

Comment: Could you provide the solution here? The information in the link might change at any time

Comment: I upped py-redis to 3.4.1 (according to the issue you provided) and everything started working properly!

Answer (score 1):

For someone who might have this issue in the future:

try `pip list` and check what version of redis is installed. I have seen this issue with 3.2.1. If that's the case try version 2.5.3 and it should work.