# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gradient_checkpointing'

Tags: python, typeerror

[this is the error and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziOFP.png) 
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZidE.png)

I have been trying to train the model using one of my own model as a pretrained model and every time I run, I get this error. The moment I use the previously used pretrained model other than my own one, I don't get that error. Please help me fix this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_init\_\_() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986089/init-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-user)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your config.json file might have missed `"gradient_checkpointing": true,`
I think this will help.